# Trigger action on default value Combo Box JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

I am trying to trigger an action on default value of the combo box when it is initialized but I'm only able to find the method to trigger an action when the value is changed using method print() set in OnAction of ComboBox.

Here is my presenter of the FXML file:

```
package tre;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class presenter implements Initializable {

    public @FXML ComboBox<String> combo;
    private final ObservableList<String> statistic = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Logged In", "Anonymous",
            "Logged Off");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        combo.setItems(statistic);
        combo.setValue("Anonymous");

        //TODO When Anonymous is displayed as default value in the combo box, it will print it.

    }

    public @FXML void print(){          
        String sel = combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(sel);

    }

}
```

Is there a solution for it? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to achieve? I don't understand the question.

Comment: @DVarga so when combo box is initialized there will be a default value but this value should have done some action in this case as changing the value in the combo box will print the new value. What I want is when the combo box is initialized it will print the default value and other actions

Comment: I'm with @DVarga - I still don't get your question. If your plan is to do some action (like calling the **print method** for **Anonymous**) when the user changed the selected item have a look at the **valueProperty** of the [ComboBox] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty--)